# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "-"

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I have the following code

```
   private String formatDate(String date)
    throws XXXXException
{
    String str = "no date";
    if (!StrUtil.isEmpty(date) && !"null".equals(date))
    {
        DateFormat dateformatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,  
        DateFormat.SHORT);
        Date dateDate;
        str = "";
        try
        {
            dateDate = dateformatter.parse(date);
            str = m_formatter.dateToString(dateDate);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            LogFactory.getLogger(XYZ.class).error("", e);

        }
    }

    return str;
 }
```

One of the user who has deployed the ear in websphere v7.0 is seeing the following 
exception

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "-"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
 .
 .
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661) 
 .
```

I dont think the issue is occurring when deployed with weblogic.Also I have not been able to replicate the issue locally with websphere v7.0 either . can the issue be with websphere
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM54864 ???
Or is there something that I can do with my code that can help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Btw., what’s the advantage of `StrUtil.isEmpty(date)` over `date.isEmpty()`? And note that your code is inconsistent. It will return `"no date"` for certain (invalid) input and `""` for certain other (also invalid) input. You should decide for one result (or behavior) for all invalid inputs. And I think I better don’t ask what `XXXXException` is…

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the java documenation for the DateFormat.SHORT (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html) it mentions a '/' character as separator. So '-' is indeed an invalid character.

I also notice the format is locale dependant. So is it possible your weblogic and websphere servers have a different locale ?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This looks useful but I changed my locale to chinese,used date format with hiphens , I was still not able to replicate the issue locally. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved. This was happening because we were using xslt transformation.
In the contentHandler implementation file ,characters function was not implemented correctly.

```
   public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    throws SAXException
{
    // Reset the value
    m_value.setLength(0);
    m_value.append(ch, start, length);
    isPut = true;
}
```

The problem was with setLength(0). It worked with weblogic and not websphere as weblogic has larger buffer or something than websphere.